# How to commit working copy with subfolder checked out from another repository?

Tags: svn

I use svn to work on my project. I do changes in my local working copy and then commit them to my main repository.

Is this possible to include copy of another repository into my local copy of the project and still be possible to:

- update/diff changes on local repo with external repository (plugins, etc)
- commit those changes to my svn repository?

The workflow would be like this:

1. I make changes to my local files
2. I commit those changes to the main svn repo
3. A plugin author did changes on his repo
4. I update my local repo to include (some or all of) the plugin's changes
5. I commit those changes from my local repo to my project repo.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is called pegging in Subversion. You can add an [external](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html), and then [peg](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html) to the desired revision from the other repository.

If you want to introduce changes from the other repository, and maintain your own version controlled changes, you'll want to [export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) the other repository into the proper location within your own project, add it, and then run [merges](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.merge.html) on the revisions you want from the official repository to keep it up to date and retain your customizations.

Comment: I don't actually understand how does it help me - I exported plugin's repo folder into my project's working copy directory, than I added those files into it and commited to my project's repository. It works well when done once, but how do I track plugin's repo changes?